# How to connect speakers with sound card?

Tags: speakers, cable, connector

Guys this might sound like a stupid question but please bear with me. I have just bought a "Asus Xonar U7 sound card" and "Logitech Z623 speakers". Now I thought this would be a simple setup (I have always used built-in sound card of my PC) so when I opened U7 sound card, I found that it has RCA output for left and right speakers.

Now Z623 does have RCA input I believe. As this is the first time I am ever dealing with RCA, I have no idea how to connect these together. Do I use RCA-to-RCA cable or some other cable?

btw as I googling for the solution, I read on some forum that U7 doesn't support 2.1 speakers. Is that true ?

Links for the products :

[Logitech Z623 Speakers](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/speaker-system-z623)

[Asus Xonar U7](https://www.asus.com/Sound-Cards/Xonar_U7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The speakers:

- have a *stereo pair* of *regular* **RCA** *input sockets;*
- and also a *stereo* **3.5mm TRS** *AUX input socket.*

---

## The soundcard:

- has a *stereo pair* of *regular* **RCA** *output sockets;*
- and also a *stereo* **3.5mm TRS** *AUX output socket.*

---

## The compatible cable configurations:

- *stereo pair* **RCA** *plugs.* <†> *stereo* **3.5mm TRS** *plug*.
- *stereo pair* **RCA** *plugs.* <‡> *stereo pair* **RCA** *plugs*.
- *stereo* **3.5mm TRS** *plug*. <†> *stereo pair* **RCA** *plugs*.
- *stereo* **3.5mm TRS** *plug*. <‡> *stereo* **3.5mm TRS** *plug*.

---

## The comments:

- the soundcard will work fine with this 2.1 speaker system.
- the bundled software probably has 7.1 channel control features etc.
- which is likely to be what the support comments were referring to.

Answer (score 1):

These speakers include a 3.5 mm audio cable that enables you to connect them like headphones. You can plug the speakers into the audio interface’s headphone output, at least for now.

The speakers also have RCA inputs, so what you ultimately want would be a very standard cable with stereo RCA male plugs at both ends. I recommend you get a high-quality name-brand cable because you want solid, trouble-free connections at both ends.